# Using text within a field 1 to validate text in field 2 - Access 2010

Tags: validation, ms-access, text

I am having trouble finding the answer to my question, or even if its possible. The overview is that I need to validate large amounts of data between two tables. Both share a primary ID code, however much of the information has been miss aligned. I want to take a text field, a one word catagory like PLUMBING and I would like to search another field within the same row to determine if the primary word is in the second field (the second field is not a standardized catagory and written as a sentence).

```
Field 1 = Plumbing
Field 2 = PLUMBING -Faucet Not Working
Field 3 = True/False
```

Field 2 is not standard which prevents me from parsing the text into a standard order. Ideally I would like to create a keyword search that can take field 1 and identify if that word appears anywhere within field 2.

Any help or guidence would be appreciated, I am at a loss for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InStr function in a query to accomplish this! Here's a link to the formal documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445031(v=vs.60).aspx

Paste this syntax into a field in a query and modify the field names accordningly:

```
InStr(1,[Field 2],[Field 1]) <> 0
```

This will return a boolean whether or not the word in the first field exists in the second field. Note, removing the "<> 0" will return the approximate location where first field word exists in the second field string. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is a great response, does wildcard also work with the function? As in one Field will have Floor Cleaning while the other will have Floor Repair, or will I need to make sure that at least one field on contains a primary key word?

Comment: I'm a little unsure by what you mean. Are you saying that you would like Field 3 to return TRUE since both fields contain "Floor" ? If so, I do not think this would be possible inside a query. This would have to be done with VBA which add more a little more complexity but is doable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Select Field1, Field2, InStr([Field2],[Field1])>0 As Field3
From YourTable
```